# Opening and termination an app from a browser window in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

How do I open and close an online SharePoint app in a browser window,

for example, the Onenote Online version of the SharePoint app? In my situation whenever I try to exit Onenote it logs me completely out of the site.

I guess this is a general question about opening and terminating an app from a browser window in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your case with Chrome browser. Signing in to https://portal.office.com which takes me to the apps collection looking like this:

[image]

Clicking on OneNote Webapp, it opens up a new browser window in Chrome. I edited one OneNote ion the browser, and later on closed the OneNote tab. I'm still signed in on the startpage, and can safely open another app. Opening Mail went fine, and no sign in was required.

I'm not sure whats casing this error, but you could clear the browser cache, and if that doesn't help - ask your administrator to send a service request to Microsoft, here: https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal

[image]

Comment: Sorry there was an important component that I unintentionally failed to mention. And was that the launch point was from a custom UI app that has a link to OneNote. How can I achieve your test experience in this situation. So that once Oneone is closed, you return to the launch point.